# Text string must be rendered within a <Text> Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {Math.floor(time/60).toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" + 
                    (time % 60).toString().padStart(2,"0")} </Text>{" "}
  </View>{" "}
       <View style={styles.containerbtn}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={()=>startTimer()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Start </Text>{" "}
        </TouchableOpacity>{" "}
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Reset </Text>{" "}
        </TouchableOpacity>{" "}
  </View>{" "}
```

If you look the code it is giving an error but don't know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey wherever you have `{" "}` you need to delete it since its a text and only meant for it to be rendered in `Text`

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {Math.floor(time/60).toString().padStart(2,"0") + ":" + 
                    (time % 60).toString().padStart(2,"0")} </Text>
  </View>
       <View style={styles.containerbtn}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={()=>startTimer()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Start </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Reset </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Do lemme know in case of any concerns

Answer (score 0):

It is because of extra `{" "}` after `</View>` and `</Text>`

If you want to render space/text, it must be inside `<Text>`